# Как устанить ошибку при установке visual studio 2017?

Tags: windows, установка, реестр

Скачал инсталятор visual studio community 2017 с оф. сайта. Запустил, появилось сообщение: 
Не удалось скачать установочные файлы. Проверьте подключение к Интернету и повторите попытку.

Сертификаты установил по инструкции. Думаю, что проблема в отключенных службах. Когда-то давно отключал. Может ли быть проблема в этом? Если, да то как восстановить службы по умолчанию? все сразу?

Comment: А подключение к интернету у вас есть? :-D

Comment: Есть. Так же я пробовал ставить студию с торрента для которой подключение не нужно.

Comment: А еще можно поставить мингв, после чего забыть о студии. Что я и сделал. Эта гадость (студия) у меня засрала всю систему, запросила перезагрузку, которую нельзя было делать, а потом выяснилось, что эта дрянь даже не начинала себя устанавливать.

Comment: Мне нужна была `visio studio` 2017 для того чтобы работать с .net core. Потому, в [официальных доках](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api/%22%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85%22) было написано так. Но мой друг мне посоветовал простое решение - [rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/). Довольно шустрая среда разработки от jetbrains.

Comment: @bukkojot что предлагает mingw в качестве IDE?

Comment: Ничего. И это прекрасно, так как не тянет за собой мусор. Но если очень хочется, то есть к примеру, http://vaultec.mbnet.fi/mingwstudio.php - впрочем я никогда этим не пользовался и предпочитаю far/mc, в зависимости от того что ближе.

Answer (score 1):

Win+R ➜ services.msc ➜ Изоляция ключей CNG ➜ Поменять тип запуска на «Вручную», запустить её ➜ Запустить установщик Visual Studio ➜ Радоваться